# Exception handling in c#

Tags: c#, exception

I know how to use try...catch block in c#. Also know why it is using. but what is exact meaning of Exception handling ? see once i write the try {}.. Catch{} i handled null exception then what should happen? what are the standard for exception handling. means what should happen is normally expected if exception occur ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The try, throw, and catch statements implement exception handling. With C++ exception handling, your program can communicate unexpected events to a higher execution context that is better able to recover from such abnormal events.
For more details log on to http://www.tictacdo.com/

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, do a search for [C# exception handling](http://www.liquidjelly.co.uk/supersearch/?q=C%23%20exception%20handling&lang=en-GB) on a good search engine. This will yield lots of good tutorials and results.

If you have a specific question on a specific exception handling scenario that you need to deal with can you post more information?

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia says

> Exception handling is a programming language construct or computer hardware mechanism designed to handle the occurrence of exceptions, special conditions that change the normal flow of program execution.

After caching an exception, if a program can recover from the exception condition, it's safe to do so.
Otherwise you need to log an informative error message and then you should stop the program.